# Is it possible to get a file in webmethod using path through Jquery .ajax() method?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

As far as I know it is not possible to send a file to webmethod using Jquery/Ajax call. But what if I send the path of the file? And use that path to get the file in webmethod?

**Client Side:**

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/UploadFile",
            data: JSON.stringify({ name: $('#fileData').val(); }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function (data, status) {
                console.log("CallWM");
                alert(data.d);
            },
            failure: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            }
        });
```

**WebMethod:**

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string UploadFile(string name)
    {
        byte[] buffer;
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"D:\Untitled.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        try
        {
            int length = (int)fileStream.Length;  // get file length
            buffer = new byte[length];            // create buffer
            int count;                            // actual number of bytes read
            int sum = 0;                          // total number of bytes read

            // read until Read method returns 0 (end of the stream has been reached)
            while ((count = fileStream.Read(buffer, sum, length - sum)) > 0)
                sum += count;  // sum is a buffer offset for next reading
        }
        finally
        {
            fileStream.Close();
        }

        return "a";
    }
```

Could this work? I think most modern browsers do not let you get real path of the file. Is there a workaround or something?

Answer (score 1):

No, this could not work.
Hmm, you are talking about two different things. The file path you send will be resolved on the server. If you want to upload a file, you need to send it from the client. You mixed a lot up.

Imagine, you try to send this to the server: `C:\Users\yourName\Test.txt`, 
where do you thing the server will try to find the file? The server will search on his local drive.

Try to use the default way to upload files. Maybe with some jQuery plugin and you make a request in the background. The internet will provide a lot of tutorials for your scenario. Just google a little bit around.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda suspected that server will look for the file on the local machine. But since my webmethod is in the code behind of aspx and not on a different webservice, I had  a little bit hope.  I googled a lot. There are many plugins but, my scenerio is that I have a form that is supposed to save textboex,dropdowns and file on a button click. I do not want postback to occur. Couldnt find any plugin that would allow me to send all this data on a button click along with the file

Comment: Interesting that you've titled your code with "Client Side" but then used "WebMethod" - instead of "WebMethod", it should read "Server Side", which will then make it clearer where the webmethod is running: on the server

Answer (score 0):

No, this won't work. if you want to upload file without post back for the entire page you could use iframe and set the target of your submitted form to this iframe

Answer (score 0):

Not sure though but you can try by **HttpPostedFileBase**

```
foreach (string one in Request.Files)
{
     HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[one];
     if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) &&    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
     {
         string fileName = file.FileName;
         string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
         byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
         BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
         byte[] binData = b.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can send a file to a webmethod just to simplify things use Base64

read your files to bytes convert your bytes to Base64 for example

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "filename.extension"));
```

then you can convert to Base64

```
var stringBase64=Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

then in the other side convert the received base64 string to bytes

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ReceivedString);
```

That is all